# Visual Studio add in to provide solution statistics

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Years ago I used to have a visual studio plug in (2003 era) which produced a nice little report showing number of lines per code by solution, then project then class, etc.

I've been looking for something similar ever since with no joy. Can anyone recommend one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not exactly what you want but doesn't do [Code Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx) the job? And if you want to extract them there are [Powertools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9422) for it.

PS: I think you need professional or above for this.

Comment: ok - as a simple .net developer I never considered this but of course this is right. As Ian posted some questions on WPF this might be helpful after all so I let it stand for now.

Comment: Thanks Carsten. It's not quite what I was looking for, but interestingly I've just upgraded to Ultimate from Pro, so I now have the Analysis tools. So I think it's only available in Ultimate and Premium(?) I've found a tool called MZ-Tools which does reporting, so I'm going to play with that for a bit.

Comment: Sorry Confused, I wasn't helping by not explaining what I do. I work almost entirely in C#

Comment: Well, MZ-Tools appears to do what I want, but it doesn't seem to cope with big projects and dies with out of memory errors :/ Just FYI.